# Selecionar duas opções no menu drop down com Selenium + Python não funciona

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import  webdriver
from time import sleep
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select        
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select  

url = "https://www.viprbrc.org/brc/vipr_genome_search.spg?method=ShowCleanSearch&decorator=flavi_dengue"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(xxxx)
browser.get(url)
sleep(20)


box_drp_x= browser.find_element_by_id("hosts").click()
box_dpr = browser.find_element_by_id("hostsBox")
human_host = Select(box_drp)
human_host.select_by_value("Human")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para selecionar duas opções no menu drop down (Human e Mosquito)? Meu código roda mas não seleciona, o que pode estar ocorrendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, sou iniciante de python e tentei de várias formas usar a opção select mas não obtive exito pois ele insiste em dizer que o botão não está visível ou não é possível interagir com o mesmo, porém com o seguinte código eu consegui digitas as duas opções no campo e seleciona-las:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://www.viprbrc.org/brc/vipr_genome_search.spg?method=ShowCleanSearch&decorator=flavi_dengue"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="hosts"]').click()
input_field = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Choose a Host..."]')
hosts = ['Human', 'Mosquito']

for value in hosts:
    input_field.send_keys(value)
    input_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Antes de tudo eu dei um clique na div hosts e com isso usando : selenium.webdriver.common.keys eu enviei o textos Human e Mosquito para o campo input pressionando o Enter logo em seguida, aparentemente algo esconde a real seleção.

**EDIT**

O problema de não conseguir selecionar o select creio que seja porque ele está com o "display-style: none", mesmo eu executando para mudar ele para "block" ele não consegue fazer a seleção, olhando melhor o fonte vi que a seleção na verdade ocorre aqui:

[image: Lugar correto onde é feita a escolha]

O que é possível ver com esse código:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = "https://www.viprbrc.org/brc/vipr_genome_search.spg?method=ShowCleanSearch&decorator=flavi_dengue"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
sleep(3)
menu = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="hosts"]')
menu.click()
hosts = menu.find_elements_by_xpath('//div/ul/li[@class="active-result"]')
for value in hosts:
    if value.text == 'Human':
        value.click()
    else:
        pass
```

Nesse segundo exemplo precisaria só alterar para clicar nos dois valores